# I can't boot elementary OS from usb

Tags: usb, filesystem

I can't boot from usb cuz this error:
[image: that error]

And I am don't know why this error appears. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the file again and verify the checksum. Instructions are in the [installation guide](https://elementary.io/docs/installation).
You can also try flashing a different USB flash drive.